# I want to know the actual amount of data in the UDP packet

Tags: sockets, udp, packet

I want to send and receive voice data using the UDP socket and Wi-Fi networks. However, I would like to know the actual size of the data contained in data packets when receiving voice data in order to make sure that the incoming properly. How do you know the actual size of the data in the packet.

Comment: 'Too broad'? Come off it.

Comment: @EJP: Okay, how about "shows no research effort"?

Comment: @EJP: Yes, too broad... does the OP mean: how do I sniff (wireshark, airsnort, whatever) at the sending vs receiving?  How do I get the raw packets data from within my program?  What are ways to include tag/checksum/etc. (which tends to end up being how do I end up reimplementing TCP badly in UDP)  Something something carrier pigeons?

Comment: @Foon The answer appears below and it is given by the value returned by `recv()` and `recvfrom()`. The alternative interpretations you mention are merely pointless invention on your part. The words 'raw packet' and 'checksum' and 'TCP' do not appear in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The functions that receive a UDP packet, `recv` and `recvfrom`, return the number of bytes received.